# add wordpress file picker in the visual editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I wonder how I can add a file picker (the default wordpress librairy would be perfect) into my tinymce visual editor's popup.

at the moment I have a field where I have to past the url of the picture, if I could add a button to pick a picture from my library instead, it would be great !

[image: What I try to achieve]

Here is what I have so far

```
editor.addButton('thumbnail', {
            title: 'Thumbnail',
            image: url+'/../images/icon-thumbnail.png',
            onclick: function() {
                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Thumbnail',
                    width: 940,
                    height: 150,
                    body: [
    //I have to change this line--------->  {type: 'textbox', name: 'url', label: 'Media URL'},<----- Is there an option to put a filepicker here ?
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'caption', label: 'Caption'},
                        {type: 'checkbox', name: 'lightbox', value: '1', label: 'Lightbox'}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        if(e.data.url==''){
                            alert('you have to provide the media\'s URL');
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }else{
                            // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                            var shortCode = '[thumbnail url="'+e.data.url+'"';
                            if(e.data.caption != ''){
                                shortCode = shortCode+' caption="'+e.data.caption+'"';
                            }
                            if(e.data.lightbox){
                                shortCode = shortCode+' lightbox=true';
                            }
                            shortCode = shortCode+' ]';
                            editor.insertContent(shortCode);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Here is how you can add a custom button in TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton All you need to so is to adjust your wordpress settings regarding the tinymce init.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I already have my button and it render my popup windows (the picture attach to my question) in fact I just need to replace the textfield in that popup by a filepicker

Answer (score -1):

You can read [this](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/) useful article, [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/properly-add-an-upload-media-button-in-a-meta-box-field) also may help.

I dont't want to copy-paste the text from articles, but basically you have to create custom PHP function in your theme's `functions.php` file which will handle media dialog display, and then include it with `add_action()` on event `admin_print_scripts`.

The last part is usage of some JavaScript and the uploader inside, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```